# Preact class attribute is empty

Tags: css, webpack, preact

Today I am trying to use CSS in preact with webpack.
It is almost working for me.

This is target code. In browser class attribute is empty. I tried className with same result, but CSS code is included in bundle.

```
import css from './todo-list.css';

export class C extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1 class={css.bordered}>title</h1>;
  }
}
```

If I just import css and don't reference it anywhere from the code
then CSS code is skipped.

So as for now my workaround is to reference css somewhere and hardcode CSS classes as string literals.

```
import css from './styles.css';

export class C extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1 class='bordered'><span class={css}>title</span></h1>;
  }
}
```

I wasn't able to spot any issue with className for preact. It looks like it supported out of the box without.
Any ideas about debugging class attribute are appreciated.

Versions:

```
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "preact": "^8.4.2",
    "webpack": "^4.28.1"
```

Loader configuration:

```
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
```

In browser css is a function and it returns empty object:

```
_todo_list_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default
ƒ getModuleExports() { return module; }
```

Comment: I would think `class={css.bordered}` would return Object that contains style in it so this may work `style={css.bordered}` but your expectation is `css.bordered` to return string, you can verify that by doing console.log

Answer (score 0):

Solution came after discovering the way how to configure webpack plugins when they are piped.

This configuration worked out for me:

```
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'      
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true
            }
          }
        ]         
      }
```